# Как изменить индексы элементов при срезе DataFrame в Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Имеется DataFrame `df_ab` в который считывается 100.000 строк из файла `csv`.
Делается срез чётных `df_ab[0::2]` и нечётных `df_ab[1::2]` элементов.
Получается 2 DataFrame `df_a` и `df_b`, но индексы у них тоже чередуются.

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame()
df_b = pd.DataFrame()
# пример из 1 столбца на 10 элементов (исходно 2 столбца)
df_ab = pd.DataFrame({'AB': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

df_a = df_ab[0::2]
df_b = df_ab[1::2]

df_a = df_a.astype('int32')
df_b = df_b.astype('int32')
print('\na:\n', df_a)
print('\nb:\n', df_b)
```

Выводит:

```
a:
    AB
0   0
2   2
4   4
6   6
8   8

b:
    AB
1   1
3   3
5   5
7   7
9   9
```

Как сделать что бы индексы шли по порядку:

```
a:
    AB
0   0
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   8

b:
    AB
0   1
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   9
```

Comment: Это срезы одной таблицы, все равно что в базе данных если удалите элемент то id всех элементов сместятся в лево, получится полная ерунда и теряется смысл вообще подобных конструкций. Если вам так уж прямо это нужно ну создайте два новых Фрейма и все.

Comment: В исходном фрейме несколько столбцов и в дальнейшем нужно сравнивать поэлементно новые фреймы-срезы, а с разными индексами этого сделать нельзя. Как Вы предлагаете я не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот решение:

```
import pandas as pd

df_ab = pd.DataFrame({'AB': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})


even = df_ab[::2].reset_index(drop=True)
odd = df_ab[1::2].reset_index(drop=True)

print(even)
print(odd)
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще один вариант:

```
In [2]: df_a.index = np.arange(len(df_a))

In [3]: df_b.index = np.arange(len(df_b))

In [4]: df_a
Out[4]:
   AB
0   0
1   2
2   4
3   6
4   8

In [5]: df_b
Out[5]:
   AB
0   1
1   3
2   5
3   7
4   9
```